# Count / Group Null and Not Null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 2 fileds a date and a string (there are more fileds but only these to are interesting for this) the string can be empty. Now I want to count how many strings are empty and how many are not.

```
SELECT 
  `date`, `serial`, count(`serial`) as count 
FROM 
  `updates` 
WHERE 
  `date` BETWEEN '2012-11-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY 
  `serial`
```

This is my code at the moment. I don't really know how to aggregate this in a good way.

Greetings
Alex

// EDIT

As Result I want to have:

```
2012-11-25    NULL        2452
2012-11-25    NOT NULL    3476
```

Comment: Can you give a sample result data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count nulls strings, and not nulls, you could use this:

```
SELECT
  `date`,
  count(`serial`) as count_not_nulls,
  count(case when `serial` is null then 1 end) as count_nulls
FROM `updates`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2012-11-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `date`
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT `date`, 'NOT NULL', count(`serial`) as count
FROM `updates`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2012-11-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59'
     AND `serial` is not null
GROUP BY `date`
UNION
SELECT `date`, 'NULL', count(1) as count
FROM `updates`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2012-11-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59'
      AND `serial` is null
GROUP BY `date`
```

Comment: Thats the right direction, but all I want (as result) is:

2012-11-25    NULL    2452
2012-11-25    NOT NULL    3476

Answer (score 1):

in short and straight

```
SELECT 
  DATE( `date` ) the_date, 
  CASE WHEN serial IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END sernull, 
  COUNT(*)
FROM 
  updates
WHERE
  DATE( `date` ) = '2012-11-25'
GROUP BY 
  the_date, 
  sernull
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91039/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

this gives you the count where serial are not null

```
SELECT `date`, `serial`, count(`serial`) as count
FROM `updates`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2012-11-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59' 
and serial is not null
GROUP BY `serial`
```

this gives you the count where serial are null

```
SELECT `date`, `serial`, count(`serial`) as count
FROM `updates`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2012-11-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59' 
and serial is  null
GROUP BY `serial`
```

Comment: Yes I know I can do it in two statements but how do I get this in one statement?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may helpful to you.Try this-

```
SELECT 'date','serial',count('serial') as count
FROM
(SELECT 'date',
           CASE WHEN 'serial'  is null THEN `NULL'
                   ELSE 'NOT NULL' END as serial
FROM `updates` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2012-11-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-25 23:59:59' )
GROUP BY 'date,'serial'
```

Good Luck!